# Shopify - Adding slider functionality

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I had created a multicolumn section in which I want to add slider functionality. But I'm not getting the desired result. I'm using Splide Js library. On big screen it should show 3 columns as a single slide and when click on arrows it move to next slide

```
footer-multicolumn.liquid:
{% comment %}theme-check-disable UndefinedObject{% endcomment %}
{{ 'section-footer-multicolumn.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
<script src="{{ 'splide.min.js' | asset_url }}" defer></script>
{{ 'splide.min.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

<div class="dawn-footer-multicolumn">
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
          <div class="slide">
            <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">
              <img src="{{ block.settings.myImage | img_url: 'master' }}">
            </a>
            <h2>
              <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">{{ block.settings.title }}</a>
            </h2>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-arrows">
  <span class="arrow prev">&lt;</span>
  <span class="arrow next">&gt;</span>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const prevArrow = document.querySelector('.slider-arrows .prev');
    const nextArrow = document.querySelector('.slider-arrows .next');
    let currentIndex = 0;

    prevArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (currentIndex > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
      } else {
        currentIndex = slides.length - 1;
      }
      updateSlideVisibility();
    });

    nextArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (currentIndex < slides.length - 1) {
        currentIndex++;
      } else {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      updateSlideVisibility();
    });

    function updateSlideVisibility() {
      slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
        if (index >= currentIndex && index < currentIndex + 3) {
          slide.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          slide.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }

    updateSlideVisibility();
  });
</script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Footer - Multicolumn",
  "settings": [],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "multicolumn_section",
      "name": "Multicolumn Section",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "label": "Select Image",
          "id": "myImage"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Title",
          "id": "title"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "label": "Link",
          "id": "link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Footer - Multicolumn",
      "category": "Custom"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

```
Css:
.dawn-footer-multicolumn {
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.multicolumn-section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px); /* Adjust the spacing between slides */
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slide h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.slider-arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slider-arrows .arrow {
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-arrows .arrow:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVicT.png)

I'm newbie here pls do coorperate

[This is I want for my multicolumn section and it should be placed horizontally center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htG23.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised you are making this work by yourself, considering your professional duties as a big international star, miss Swift, but... by the way.... :D

The first things I notice reading your code are that:

1. You're not using the suggested structure. In the [Structure section](https://splidejs.com/guides/structure/), Splide tells you to use a specific structure for your carousel:

   ```
   <section class="splide" aria-label="Basic Structure Example">
     <div class="splide__track">
       <ul class="splide__list">
         <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
         <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
         <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
   </section>
   ```

   You can use `<div>`s instead of the section and list tags, but you must use all of the `splide__???` classes, and you must respect a specific sequence.

   For example, you can put additional childs between the root element (the one with the `splide` class), and the track element (the one with the `splide__track` class), but you can not put anything between the track element and the list element (the one with the `splide__list` class).

   So you can do this:

   ```
   <section class="splide" aria-label="Restriction Example">
     <div>
       <div>
         <div>
           <div class="splide__track">
             <ul class="splide__list">
   ```

   but you can't do this:

   ```
   <section class="splide" aria-label="Incorrect Structure Example">
     <div class="splide__track">
       <div>
         <ul class="splide__list">
   ```
2. The second, and even more important thing, is that after creating the correct structure, you must apply Splide to the root element of that structure, or splide will never work. So, let' say you have a structure like the basic one I showed you before:

   ```
    <section class="splide" aria-label="Basic Structure Example">
     <div class="splide__track">
      <ul class="splide__list">
       <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
       <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
       <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </section>
   ```

   In your javascript code you must write something like this:

   ```
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {  // Make sure your element has been created

     var splide = new Splide( '.splide' );  // Construct the Splide object passing the class of the carousel's root element
     splide.mount();  // Initialize the splide instance. 

    });
   ```

If you follow these rules you will get a basic slider. If you want more control ont he functionalities, like having a looping carousel instead of a slider, enabling autoplay and many other things, you have to pass an option object to the constructor. You can find how to do it, and a list of the options, [here](https://splidejs.com/guides/options/). Options can also be passed through a data attribute set to the root element of the slider/carousel.